# Error : django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type bytea to boolean

Tags: django, heroku, django-models

I am running a migrate command on heroku from my django project and I am getting this error.

I am using Sqlite3

Thanks in advance.

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type bytea to boolean
LINE 1: ...R COLUMN "available" TYPE boolean USING "available"::boolean
```

This is the class it is referring to.
I tried adding a default=1, blank=False to the boolean **options and no luck.

```
   class Cat(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True)
        available = models.BooleanField()
```

Comment: Did you change the type of the `available` field, if so what was it before?

Comment: WAAAY before it was a binary field, but i made migrations and migrated on my local before pushing to git and heroku, i'm using sqlite3 btw.

Answer (score 1):

You are using PostgreSQL on heroku and you can't convert from a `BinaryField` to a `BooleanField` because postgres doesn't know how to convert from one to the other.

Remove the `AlterField` operation from your migration and replace it with two operations that delete the existing field and then create a new field

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        (<app_name>, <previous>),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='cat',
            name='available',
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='cat',
            name='available',
            field=models.BooleanField(default=False),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks Iain, is there a reason why I don't just delete all the migrations and just start it from scratch?  I ended up doing that before I saw this and it seemed to work.

Comment: If you don't care about any of your data you can just delete your migrations files and create initial ones from scratch and then delete and recreate your DB. If you want to keep the existing data in your DB then you will need to do similar to the above

Comment: Ahh i see gotcha gotcha, thank you so much!

Comment: your hint pointed me in the right direction, thanks for your time Iain.